# How to pass form data from angular to nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular

I am new to Angular5. I need to pass user details from angular to nodejs.

**app.component.ts:**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators, FormControl, FormArray } from 
'@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private http:Http) { } 
    onSubmit(registerForm) {
       console.log(registerForm.value);
       let url = 'http://localhost:8080/signup';
       this.http.post(url, {registerForm(registerForm)}).subscribe(res => 
          console.log(res.json()));
    }
 }
```

Now I need to pass those data to nodejs routes to proceed further.

**Node js routing file:**

```
module.exports = function(app, passport) {

app.post('/signup', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
    successRedirect : '/', 
    failureRedirect : '/',
    failureFlash : true 
}));

};
```

Now am getting the following error: Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for AppComponent: (?).

Comment: Please post your HTML content also

Comment: still, struggling ? or you got the answer?

Comment: @NikhilSavaliya please find my updated post. Getting errors.

Comment: @NikhilSavaliya here is the html form am posting:                           <form #registerForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(registerForm)">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call Your function from the `component.html` file it will trigger the function which will be in your `component.ts` file.
From this function call service which contains the function which will be requesting your node API

```
addData() {
    this.adminService.addCountry(this.form.value).subscribe(
      res => {
        var response = res.json();
        this.flashMessagesService.show(response.message, {
          cssClass: "alert-success",
          timeout: 2000
        });
      },
      error => {
        if (error.status == 401) {
          localStorage.removeItem("currentUser");
          this.router.navigate(["/"]);
        } else {
          this.flashMessagesService.show(error.json().error, {
            cssClass: "alert-danger",
            timeout: 2000
          });
        }
      }
    );
  }
```

Create admin service to call your HTTP URL which is running on node

**Service**

```
  addCountry(formData) {
    console.log(formData);
    var authToken = this.getAuthToken();
    if (authToken != "") {
      var headers = this.getHeaders();
      headers.append("Authorization", authToken);
      return this.http
        .post(
          `http://localhost:3000/addData`,
          this.formData(formData),
          { headers: headers }
        )
        .map((response: Response) => {
          return response;
        });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use service in angular to send data to nodeJs. Please refer the tutorials of Angular from Codecraft. Please have a look at https://codecraft.tv/courses/angular/http/core-http-api/

For now you need to send some registration form data. So 
1. import http module to AppModule
2. Refer to the documentation above
3. You can pass data to nodejs using a POST method of http

Answer (score 0):

I think you should look on `Observable`.
https://angular.io/guide/observables

On logic you should create server with `Observable` request to your NodeJs (express) app. Then you can add to your component function with `subscribe`.

Some code:

**Create authentication service**

`ng generate service authentication`

**Create user service for store user data (or you can only store it in other components)**

`ng generate service user`

**On authentication.service.ts create authenticate method**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { UserService } from '../user/user.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';`

@Injectable()
export class AuthenticationService {
  token: string;

  constructor(private router: Router, private httpClient: HttpClient, 
   public userService: UserService) {
     const currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
     this.token = currentUser && currentUser.token;
  }

  getToken(email: string, password: string): Observable<User> {
     return this.httpClient.post<User>(apiRoutes.authentication, 
     {userEmail: email, userPassword: password});
  }

  authenticate(email: string, password: string) {
    this.getToken(email, password).subscribe(response => {
      if (response.userToken.length > 0) {
        this.userService.user.userEmail = response.userEmail;
        this.userService.user.userToken = response.userToken;
        this.userService.user._id = response._id;
        this.userService.user.isUserAuthenticated = true;
        localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify({token: response.userToken}));
        this.router.navigate(['/']);
       // TODO: Need some error logic
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

**Now you can add to your form in template**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="this.authenticationService.authenticate(userEmail, password)">
...
</form>
```