# How to transfer data from Angular to Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript

I want to build a comment section in my Angular App. These comments are supposed to be stored in a database, so I want to forward the data from Angular to Node.js, where it can be passed on to the database. So I created an input field for comments in *detail.component.html*. The comment is saved when the user hits enter.

```html
<input #box (keyup.enter)="update(box.value)">
<p>{{value}}</p>
```

In *detail.component.ts* I save the comment in a variable:

```
public value: any= []
update(comment: any) { this.value = comment; }
//code
this.dataService.addComment().subscribe(comment => this.value = comment)
```

Here is the first problem - how do I get the comment to *data.service.ts*?

```
//code
addComment() {}
```

And then there is the actual question: How can I forward this comment to server.js in the node.js App?

I am quite new to Angular, so I am pretty clueless of how to achive this. I found this question [How to pass form data from angular to nodejs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49548283) samewhat useful, but could not apply it to my usecase. So how can I transfer the data from Angular to Node.js?

Comment: is your post api implemented in server side(nodejs)?

Comment: @SiddharthPal - yes the API is created by the server.js (nodejs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have already defined API(POST) on the server-side then you just need to call the `http.post` method like below:

```
  addComment(title: string) {
    const postData = new FormData();
    postData.append('title', title);
    return this.http
      .post<{ title: string; }>(
        '<HOST_NAME>/api/comments',
        postData
      )
  }
```

and to use it you have to subscribe it as Observables are lazy as below:

```
this.dataService.addComment(this.value).subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: I get this error message: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'.for "subscribe" in "detail.component.ts"

Comment: sorry my bad I forgot to return the Observable..Updated my answer. Please check now

Comment: In console.log I get this error message: "myhostname/api/comments 404 (Not Found)" ("cannot POST") - Do I have to somehow create this page to be able to post something there? I have in Node.js in server.js something like "app.get('/api/comments', function, req, res, next) {/*code*/}

Comment: I am not sure then you should check your api first from postman or some other client. You said that you are able to get data from api so I assume your proxy setup is correct.

Comment: Yes - getting data works all fine - I will do some troubleshooting tomorrow to find out where the problem lies :)

Comment: gotcha in your server side the api should be of POST verb not GET. 
 ```app.post('/api/comments', function, req, res, next) {/*code*/}```

Answer (score 0):

> Here is the first problem - how do I get the comment to
>   data.service.ts?

As you stated in the question that you are saving comment to a variable `value`. Pass the value variable to the service:

```
this.dataService.addComment(this.value).subscribe(res => {
  // check fo response, and maybe chain errors
});
```

> And then there is the actual question: How can I forward this comment
>   to server.js in the node.js App?

In the Data Service:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
}

addComment(comment) {
  return this.http.post<any>('server-url-route', comment);
}
```

in the Node Js:

Have a route for adding a comment and a function to save the comment to the database.

Comment: I get this error message: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'.for "subscribe" in "detail.component.ts"

Comment: @butterfly you have to use `addComment(comment) {
  return this.http.post<any>('server-url-route', comment);
}` in the Data Service.

Comment: In console.log I get this error message: "myhostname/api/comments 404 (Not Found)" ("cannot POST") - Do I have to somehow create this page to be able to post something there? I have in Node.js in server.js something like "app.get('/api/comments', function, req, res, next) {/*code*/}